# Does the lua_load() C function work with LuaJIT pre-compiled bytecode?

Tags: lua, luajit, luac

I intend to embed LuaJIT into a program of mine that uses PhysFS to load... well, stuff. Both assets and Lua scripts.

So I thought, why not pre-compile my Lua scripts?

```
luajit -b test.lua test.raw
```

I know that when using normal vanilla Lua, the lua_load() C function works fine just fine with both human-readable scripts and bytecode made with luac. But what about LuaJIT? Does the same apply to LuaJIT? Does lua_load() work with precompiled LuaJIT bytecode?

Comment: Confirmed to work

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [official site](http://luajit.org/extensions.html#string_dump)

> The generated bytecode is portable and can be loaded on any
>   architecture that LuaJIT supports, independent of word size or
>   endianess. However the bytecode compatibility versions must match

More from same page

> A file in raw bytecode format is auto-detected and can be loaded like
>   any Lua source file. E.g. directly from the command line or with
>   loadfile(), dofile() etc

Comment: Both `loadfile` and `dofile` are **LuaJit** functions, not **C** functions. OP wants to call LuaJit bytecode from **C**.

Comment: So? I assumes he uses LuaJIT library for that. Of course it will not work for different implementation of Lua.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the page you're linking to talks about the LuaJit interpreter. It doesn't say anything about running LuaJit bytecode using the C API. And I found nothing that indicates that `lua_load`, using the LuaJit C API, will correctly load LuaJit bytecode.

Comment: How do you think `loadstring` implemented? This is just lib function which implemented on top of Lua C API.

Comment: Confirmed to work.